# How Sitefinity permissions apply to oData web services?

Tags: permissions, odata, sitefinity

How Sitefinity permissions are applied when using oData web services?
Is this even possible?

**Scenario:**

- Sitefinity 10.0
- *View news* permissions changed to *Administrators only*
- Default oData service is active
- Authentication protocol: *OpenId* (not sure if this matters)

When I request `/api/default/newsitems` with *Postman or browser* as anonymous user, then all news are returned.

(I need to apply this for documents as they must be private, user related and etc., but by enabling oData, everyone can get all documents)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: maybe you send some auth cookies or tokens with the postman request?

Comment: @VeselinVasilev, yes, at first I also thought that this was the problem. But then I tested it with request in the browser, with not logged user and with script from the template. 

I just couldn't find any information about Sitefinity's oData services and permissions.

Answer (score 0):

Could you look at this [article](https://www.sitefinity.com/blogs/peter-filipov/posts/peter-filipov-blog/2017/09/27/getting-started-with-sitefinity---apis-and-providers). I have tested the scenario and I don't retrieve the items, it says that the user does not have permissions. Could you provide a live URL, so I can look at it.

Peter

Comment: Thanks, I'll check the article. I guess I'm missing something. Also I will see if I can provide more info or live URL.

Comment: I read the article, and it lead me to this [document](https://docs.sitefinity.com/change-filtering-by-view-permissions). I've changed the FilterQueriesByViewPermissions option for my site and it worked. 

But when I change view permissions for news items from **Everyone** to **Administrator** or **Backend users**, and log in as such, I can't get any news. My guess is that this is expected behavior as I don't authenticate the user with a token. Is that so? Thanks.

Comment: The authentication mechanism is the same. Do you experience this with different user role e.g. "user"?

Comment: Yes, I've just tested it. I have the same issue and I still can't fix it.

Comment: Have you been able to resolve it. Submit your project to the support team, so we can look at it internally. Also, you can record a video and show what exactly happens and post it here, so I can look at it,